# Пузырчатая сортировка в JS. Помогите?

Tags: javascript, сортировка

```js
var array = new Array(8, 4, 2, 3, 6);

document.write(array);

b = 5;

for (k = 0; k < b - 1; k++) {

  swap = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < b - k - 1; i++) {

    if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
      temp = array[i + 1];
      array[i + 1] = array[i];
      array[i] = temp;
      swap++;
    }
  }
  document.write(array[i] + " ");
}
```

Вместо отсортированного списка выводит: `8 4 2 3 68 6 4 3`.

Comment: в чем именно помочь? Что не так? Чем не нравится текущий код?

Comment: Пузырчатая? Не пузырьковая? :)

Comment: Я не верю, что это первый вопрос по "пузырчатой" сортировке на этом сайте...

Answer (score 3):

Вывод отсортированного массива нужно производить после цикла и вместо явного указания размера массива лучше использовать свойство Length

```
var array = [8, 4, 2, 3, 6];
swap =0;
for (k = 0; k < array.Length; k++) { 
    for (i = 0; i < array.Length - k - 1; i++) { 
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) { 
            temp = array[i + 1]; 
            array[i + 1] = array[i]; 
            array[i] = temp; 
            swap++;
        }
    }
}
for (i=0;i<array.Length; i++) 
    document.write(array[i] + " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

> вместо отсортированного списка выводит:---> 8,4,2,3,68 6 4 3

ну так всё правильно, `8,4,2,3,6` это ваш первый вывод перед циклом `document.write(array);`
и затем дальше пишется `8 6 4 3` вот этой строкой `document.write(array[i] + " ");` только поменяйте i на k  - `document.write(array[k] + " ");`

И вообще лучше вывод делать за циклом. Сортировка и вывод это две логически разные операции, надо такое разделять.

Answer (score 0):

Как совет: лучше написать функцию, которая будет сортировать и возвращать отсортированный массив, на мой взгляд так будет правильнее, можно будет использовать в дальнейшем. Смотреть, что получилось в результате - по завершению сортировки. Убрать неиспользуемую переменную `swap`. Пример рабочего кода:

```js
var array = new Array(8, 4, 2, 3, 6);

function BubbleSort(arr) {
  var n = arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++) {
      if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j]) {
        var temp = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

BubbleSort(array);

for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
  document.write(array[index] + " ");
```

> **Пузырьковая сортировка** выполняет следующие действия: проход
>   по массиву с обменом местами соседних элементов, нарушающих заданный
>   порядок, до тех пор, пока массив не будет окончательно отсортирован.

Очень полезная ссылка: [Алгоритмы сортировок на JavaScript](http://mathhelpplanet.com/static.php?p=javascript-algoritmy-sortirovki)

Comment: Вы же знаете, что массивы в JS передаются по ссылке? Как следствие, вы возвращаете не **новый** массив, а отсортированный исходный.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, да, написать новый - было не правильно.

Comment: Так может стоит просто избавится от побочного действия функции (сортировка **аргумента**)? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function bubleSorting(arr) {
do {
    var swaped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
            var tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = tmp;
            swaped = true;
        }
    }
}
 while(swaped != false);
return arr;
}   
var numArray = [5, 21, 6, -12, 0.2, 33];
document.write(bubleSorting(numArray));
```

Comment: Несколько раз может пройти по циклу, но по-крайнем мере не столько раз, сколько arr.length, вхолостую,  если  раньше отсортируются.... Это из книг по алгоритмам...